# SMTP Error in Swing Application

Tags: java

```
public static void sendEmail(String mailTo, String mailCC, String subject, String content) 
{
    Properties properties = System.getProperties();

    properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    properties.setProperty("mail.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");

    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.quitwait", "false");
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port","465");


    try {
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties,
                new Authenticator() {

            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                return new PasswordAuthentication(
                        "swapnilshrk@gmail.com", "XXXXXX");
            }
        });
        Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
        Address fromAddress = new InternetAddress("swapnilshrk@gmail.com");
        Address toAdd = new InternetAddress(mailTo);
        Address ccAdd = new InternetAddress(mailCC);

        message.setFrom(fromAddress);
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, toAdd);
        message.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.CC, ccAdd);
        message.setSubject(subject);           

        Transport.send(message);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

I am facing the below error.Please help

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the following things :

1.) On your Gmail Google account, you need to Enable Less Secure Apps.

Allow less secure apps

2.) Try the following set of Properties, I only added 2 additional props at the end....

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    //props.setProperty ("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
    props.setProperty ("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
    props.setProperty ("mail.smtp.user", this.getUsername());
    props.setProperty ("mail.smtp.password", this.getPassword());
    props.setProperty ("mail.smtp.port", "465");
    props.setProperty ("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");         
    props.setProperty("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
    props.setProperty ("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    props.setProperty ("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
    props.setProperty ("mail.smtp.localhost", "localhost"); // added this line
    props.setProperty ("mail.debug", "true"); // added this line
```

3.) Use an authenticated Transport/Session :

```
    Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
```

Note the session passes no Authenticator.

```
        // Send message
        //Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtps");
        Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
        transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", this.getUsername(), getPassword());
        getLog().info("Transport.....................................[" + transport.toString() + "]");
        transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
```

Note the Transport uses a connect where the gmail account and pwd are used to login.